# How to make a dictionary copy of a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple dictionary with a nested dictionary, I want to make a copy of the nested dictionary and store it in a separate dictionary. For example

{'Values': {'apple' : '5', 'pear' : '2', 'banana' : '6'}}

I want to make a copy of the key/value pairs of apple, pear, and banana, leaving out the outer 'Values' dictionary. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If the inner dictionary is nested itself, use deepcopy as follows:

```
from copy import deepcopy
d_vals = {'Values': {"Fruit": {'apple' : '5', 'pear' : '2', 'banana' : '6'}}}
d_fruit = deepcopy(d_vals["Values"])
```

Otherwise, you may just use "copy":

```
from copy import copy
d_vals = {'Values': {'apple' : '5', 'pear' : '2', 'banana' : '6'}}
d_fruit = copy(d_vals["Values"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the inner `dict` by key, then call `copy` on it.

```py
d = {'Values': {'apple' : '5', 'pear' : '2', 'banana' : '6'}}
res = d['Values'].copy() # {'apple': '5', 'pear': '2', 'banana': '6'}
```